# Yahoo Finance API

Tags: yahoo

Have been looking for ways to down load stock price data using Yahoo Finance on Chinese Stocks. Symbol that ends with .SS = stock listed in Shanghai, .zz = stock listed in Shenzhen

This link http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=000625.sz&f=snohgl1v returns

000625.SZ      CHANGAN AUTOMOBIL      12.4      12.8      12.4      12.69      9787354

This link http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=600600.SS&f=snohgl1v returns

600600.SS      600600.SS      N/A      N/A      N/A      0      N/A

I have done a few tests and and .SZ stocks return valid data but not for .SS stocks.

However using this link "table.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=600600.SS" the data is clearly there.

Really confused as to why this is the case. Anyone has any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

As for now, below API would give a nice JSON response:

```
https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/quote?lang=en-US&region=US&corsDomain=finance.yahoo.com&fields=symbol,longName,shortName,priceHint,regularMarketPrice,regularMarketChange,regularMarketChangePercent,currency,regularMarketTime,regularMarketVolume,quantity,averageDailyVolume3Month,regularMarketDayHigh,regularMarketDayLow,regularMarketPrice,regularMarketOpen,fiftyTwoWeekHigh,fiftyTwoWeekLow,regularMarketPrice,regularMarketOpen,sparkline,marketCap&symbols=000001.SS,600600.SS
```

Answer (score 2):

Yahoo Finance current quote API still does not work for SS stocks as of Feb 2016.  I ended up scraping data from the UI:

1. Login to Yahoo Finance
2. Create view (in my case v3) with fields you'll need 
   http://finance.yahoo.com/quotes/view/new?symbols=000001.SS&from_view_id=v3
3. Construct URL with your comma separated symbols (200 max) and new view version, such as 
   http://finance.yahoo.com/quotes/000001.SS,600000.SS,600004.SS,600005.SS/view/v3
4. I'm using ruby watir to get the data I need into a csv file..